# How to match one row from one column to the next 5-10 rows in another column in R?

Tags: r, match

I have a table in R (Click on the link below (See my table here)) that shows observations of two events per day: observ1 and observ2. I would like to add a third column to that called 'check'. In column check, I should get a TRUE value if observ1 equals 1 and after 5 to 10 days, observ2 also equals 1.

As you see in the table, check value on row 14 is TRUE. The reason is that observ1 was 1 on row 6 and then after 9 days, observ2 also was 1.

I do not know how to code this in R and get out column 'check'. Appreciate any assistance!

[See my table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A85xV.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not considered a good way to ask a question, generally most posters will use `dput()` on their data.frame to provide a sample of their data to upload in the question. The result of this function is copied and pasted from the console in the format I have done below (see data). For future questions it is considered good practice. At any rate hope this solutions helps:

Base R solution:

```
df1$check <- with(
  df1, 
  vapply(
    seq_along(observ2),
    function(i){
      if(i - 5 <= 0){
        NA
      }else{
        ir <- max(i-10, 1)
        ir2 <- (any(observ1[ir:(i-5)] == 1) & observ2[i] == 1)
        ifelse(ir2, ir2, NA)
        }
      },
    logical(1)
  )
)
```

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), observ1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), observ2 = c(0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for your speedy reply! This is working on my entire set. Thanks a million. And sorry about the bad post. I am new to stackoverflow. But I'll follow your advice and use dput() next time. Thanks a lot again :-)

Comment: @OlufSändrostrom no worries, please upvote and accept my solution if you have found it useful (this is the usual way to show appreciation on SO too !)

Comment: @OlufSändrostrom also hope you enjoy using SO, it as a very good community here (especially amongst the R users) !

Comment: Oh yes, sure! I just accepted and upvoted the solution @hello_friend. By the way, I was thinking the solution gonna be so complicated but yours is very straightforward and for a newbie like me easy to follow. You are awesome! Thanks once again.

Comment: Yes with your quick efficient help today, I already fell in love with SO. I would definitely need it through the path of learning R :-)

Comment: Hey @hello_friend. I need your kind help again. could you please help? I have a new column 'observe3' which has 0 and 1 values. You helped me get a TRUE value if observ1 equals 1 and after 5 to 10 days, observ2 also equals 1.
Now, I need to add a 3rd condition that if observ1 equals 1, and after 5-10 days, observ2 equals 1 AND also observ3 equals 1 within the same 5-10 days, then retrun TRUE.

Comment: it will look like this:

Comment: df1 <- structure(list(day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), observ1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), observ2 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
observ3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
check = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'TRUE', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))

Comment: But I don't know how to add that third condition into the nice vapply code you did for me earlier.

Comment: @OlufSändrostrom please ask another question and I will answer it there.

Comment: @OlufSändrostrom Please tag me in it when you have formulated the question.

Comment: thanks! sure. I'll do it right away.

Comment: just posting the link to my new question here because it didn't allow me to tag you in the new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73388232/how-to-match-one-row-from-one-column-to-the-next-5-10-rows-in-two-other-columns