# How to match one row from one column to the next 5-10 rows in two other columns in R?

Tags: r, matching

I have a  data frame which looks like this:

```
df1 <- structure(list(day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), observ1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), observ2 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
observ3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Previously I got a TRUE value if observ1 equals 1 and after 5 to 10 days, observ2 also equals 1.

Now, I need to add a 3rd condition that if observ1 equals 1, and after 5-10 days, observ2 equals 1 **AND** also observ3 equals 1 within the same 5-10 days, then retrun TRUE.

So, the new 'check' column should look like this:

```
df1 <- structure(list(day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), 
observ1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
observ2 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
observ3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
check = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'TRUE', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this helps, thanks for asking another question, this is generally considered the way to go when you need to add on to your original question btw. Im not sure this is correct, can you please give me guidance on whether or not this is what  you are after ?

```
df1$check <- with(
  df1, 
  vapply(
    seq_along(observ1),
    function(i){
      # If we are less than five days in: 
      if(i - 5 <= 0){
        # Return NA: logical scalar => env
        NA
      # Otherwise:
      }else{
        # Ensure no negative indices by setting a lower bound of 1: 
        # idx_lower_bound => integer scalar
        idx_lower_bound <- max(
          i-10, 
          1
        )
        # Compute the index: idx => integer vector
        idx <- seq(
          idx_lower_bound,
          i+5,
          by = 1
        )
        # Test if all conditions are true: 
        # check => logical scalar
        check <- all(
          # The current value of observ2 == 1 ? logical scalar
          observ1[i] == 1,
          # Any observ2 values in the range == 1 ? logical scalar
          any(observ2[idx] == 1),
          # Any observ3 values in the range == 1 ? logical scalar
          any(observ3[idx] == 1)
        )
        # Replace false with NA: logical vector => env
        ifelse(
          check, 
          check, 
          NA
        )
      }
    },
    logical(1)
  )
)
```

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(
  list(
    day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), 
    observ1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    observ2 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
    observ3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    ),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L)
)
```

Comment: Thanks very much but I'm afraid it does not do what I want. The results I get for the 'check' column is like this now: ```df1 <- structure(list(day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), observ1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), observ2 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
observ3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
check = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, TRUE)), 
 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))```

Comment: But I want the check column to look like this: ```df1 <- structure(list(day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), 
observ1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
observ2 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
observ3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
check = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'TRUE', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))```

Comment: I know it's complicated, sorry about that. I'll try to clarify. First, it should check that observ1 is '1'. And then checks if after 5-10 days, observ2 is also '1'. if so, that's the first TRUE for us. But I want that between those 5 to 10 days that observ1 and observ2 became 1, observ3 also equals 1.

Comment: That said, in the new 'check' column I should only get a TRUE on row 14.

Comment: Appreciate your kind assistance. I'm sure you know how to do this.

Comment: @OlufSändrostrom no worries mate, please see the edited solution above i think it does what you require.

Comment: O yes, that's it. thanks a lot for your great help and the great code. The comments in the code are also very helpful. You're awesome :-) Thanks again!

Comment: @OlufSändrostrom no worries, thanks for thinking of me and following SO protocol. Good luck and happy coding. Hopefully the above helped !

Comment: Yes, it was such a great help, appreciate that. I tried hard to fix it but I didn't manage on my own :-( I hope one day I become master at R like you. Thanks again and have a wonderful time.